# Pass information /current ID/ to child Controller with @PathVariable SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring

but want to ask one question. First in my app i want to register User in one form and after redirect to another form where User must fill UserDetails form. These are two Entities `User` and `UserDetail` with OneToOne Relation. In my second Controller `UserDetailController` I want to pass `UserId` property from `User`, I made research but cant find the answer how. I try with `@PathVariable`, but its not working.
    Here part of my code:

```
abstract class BaseController {

    protected ModelAndView view(String view, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.setViewName(view);

        return modelAndView;
    }

   protected ModelAndView view(String view) {
        return this.view(view, new ModelAndView());
    }

    protected ModelAndView redirect(String route) {
        return this.view("redirect:" + route);
    }
}
```

UserController

```
        @GetMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView register() {
                return this.view("register");
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView registerConfirm(@ModelAttribute UserRegisterBindingModel userRegisterBindingModel,
                                        HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request
                                        ) {
        if (!userRegisterBindingModel.getPassword()
                .equals(userRegisterBindingModel.getConfirmPassword())) {
            return this.view("register");
        }



        this.userService.createUser(this.modelMapper.map(userRegisterBindingModel, UserServiceModel.class));
        String id = request.getParameter("userId");
        return this.redirect("user-profile/" + id);
    }
```

UserDetailController

```
 @GetMapping("/user-profile/{id}")
    public ModelAndView add(@PathVariable String id) {

        return this.view("user-profile");
    }
```

This code doesn't work, because  "id" return NULL. How to pass from register to user-profile/{id} --> id ?

Thаnks for helping me.

Comment: You can also have a look at [Spring MVC support for RedirectAttributes with FlashAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

In registerConfirmMethod

```
model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/user-profile", model);
```

In last method you would have to add

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user-profile");
modelAndView.addObject("id", id);
return modelAndView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectView something like this

When you add attribute with "id"

variable '{id}' matches with a model attribute, so it will be automatically substituted as pathparam in redirect URL

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public RedirectView registerConfirm(@ModelAttribute UserRegisterBindingModel userRegisterBindingModel,
                                HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, Model model
                                ) {


    this.userService.createUser(this.modelMapper.
    map(userRegisterBindingModel, UserServiceModel.class));

    String id = request.getParameter("userId");

    model.addAttribute("id", id);

    RedirectView rv = new RedirectView();
    rv.setContextRelative(true);
    rv.setUrl("/user-profile/{id}");
    return rv;
}
```

and in your user-profile controller

```
@GetMapping("/user-profie/{id}")
public ModelAndView add(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

   //  sout id
    return this.view("user-profile");
}
```

Comment: String id = request.getParameter("userId");

    model.addAttribute("id", id); This return NULL. How can i get id ? from register User. THanks